# Gulp завершает работу если JS допустить ошибку, как этого избежать?

Tags: gulp, npm, gulp-uglify

Eсли в JS допустить ошибку то `gulp watch` прекращает свою работу и вы дает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таск `uglify`:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
return gulp.src([
    'app/js/libs/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    'app/js/libs/slick.min.js',
    'app/js/common.js'
])
.pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

Как сделать так чтоб не прекращалась работа `gulp watch` , а писало что ошибка в таком-то файле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользоваться плагином **[gulp-plumber](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber)**.

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('scripts', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/scripts')
  .pipe(plumber())
  // весь остальной код таска
});
```

Comment: да, спс, только прочел про это